# nginx redirecting to wrong vhost when both hosts use ssl

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have 2 virtual hosts configured in nginx and both using ssl in a way that http://www.firstsite.com redirects to https://www.firstsite.com and it works correctly, the problem is that http://www.secondsite.com is not redirecting to https://www.secondsite.com, but to https://www.firstsite.com

this is the first config file

```
server {
     listen 80; 
     return 301 https://www.dianadelvalle.com$request_uri;
     server_name www.dianadelvalle.com;

  }
  server{
      listen 443 ssl;
      ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.koohack.com/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.koohack.com/privkey.pem;

      root /home/pi/www.dianadelvalle.com/;

    index commingsoon.html index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

      server_name www.dianadelvalle.com;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

      # max upload size
      client_max_body_size 5M;   # adjust to taste

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
  }
```

and the second config file:

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/pi/koohack/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    #server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.koohack.com;
    return 301 https://www.koohack.com$request_uri;
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    listen 443  ssl;
    server_name www.koohack.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.koohack.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.koohack.com/privkey.pem;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 15M;   # adjust to taste

    if (-f /home/pi/koohack/.maintenance) {
         return 503;
    }

   error_page 503 @maintenance;
   location @maintenance {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /home/pi/koohack/static/maintenance.html break;
   }

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/pi/koohack/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/pi/koohack/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
    location /.well-known {
        alias /home/pi/koohack/.well-known;
    }
}
```

I spared the server name, log and certificate paths for clarity. What I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Necessary note: I already looked to [this possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797397/nginx-redirecting-to-wrong-vhost) to avoid content duplication but it didn't help

Comment: Use `nginx -t` and `nginx -T` to test and view the configuration. You say you have redacted the `server_name` statements, which makes commenting on your configuration difficult. `nginx` will use the `default_server` if it cannot find a match for the requested domain name. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more.

Comment: Do you have the `server_name` defined in the `listen 80` block of your config or not?

Comment: I just updated to post using the real conf files, hope is clearer now to you guys @RichardSmith and @"Tarun Lalwani". Sorry foro the late response I was so busy lastnight :)

Comment: Obviously the third `server` block only matches if the `www` is included in the domain name. Check the spelling, check the configuration using the commands in my previous comment, check the access log (as that will probably tell you what is happening), make sure you restart the server and clear your browser cache between any changes.

Comment: Man, this is insane! I didn't change anything at all and now is working as it was supposed to be! I'm gonna select your answer as the solution since you were the person whom replied most of the times. Thanks for your time

Comment: @RichardSmith can't find the green check icon to select your answer as the soution, I think you have to make a separated comment for that

Comment: I have not written an answer - the above is only a comment - I am glad that it is working now - I will flag this question as not longer reproducible.

Comment: I just wanted to reward you for your time, thanks anyway

Comment: @RichardSmith the problem persists, can you think of any way to diagnose what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

You may have the following configs:

```
server_name my.domain.com;
ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/chain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/my.domain.key;
```

Check that your second site is also listening on ssl ports.

```
 listen 443 ssl;
 listen [::]:443 ssl;
```

If the 2nd site is missing the listening config, it will redirect to default, regardless of the ssl certificate configs.